# How to import a large data file without having the contents printed to the screen?

Tags: import

I have a long, 3-column, data file "sdat1".
When I write
mydata = Import["/Users/prowat/Desktop/Mydirectory/sdat1", "Table"]
Mathematica prints out the whole contents, which I do not want.
How can I stop this?

Comment: Add a semicolon, `;` to the end.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. Please don't be discouraged by the close vote and take a glimpse at the help center to see which types of questions are off-topic. Those include the questions that can be answered by reading the Mathematica manual, such as this one.